# Cannot Buying ETH or other coins using Coinbase PHP API

Tags: php, api, coinbase-api

I am currently using Coinbase php API. I have try to buy ETH  with the following code:

```
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Sell;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Buy;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\Param;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Exception;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;


$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);  

$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
$account = $client->getPrimaryAccount(); // or some other account

$buy = new Buy([
'amount' => new Money(0.05, CurrencyCode::ETH), 
'currency' => CurrencyCode::ETH
]);

$client->createAccountBuy($accounts, $buy, [Param::COMMIT => false]);
//$selldetail = $client->commitSell($sell);


$PaymentDetail = $client->decodeLastResponse();
//$PaymentArray =  $PaymentDetail['data'];


echo '<pre>';
print_r($PaymentDetail);
echo '</pre>';
```

The code is throwing this error:

> Message Uncaught TypeError: Argument
>   1 passed to Coinbase\Wallet\Client::createAccountBuy() must be an
>   instance of Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account, instance of
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\coinbase\cb_coin.php on line 154 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\coinbase\src\Client.php:421 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\coinbase\cb_coin.php(154):
>   Coinbase\Wallet\Client->createAccountBuy(Object(Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\ResourceCollection), Object(Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Buy), Array) #1 {main} thrown

Answer (score 0):

`$accounts = $client->getAccounts();` returns a list, but `$client->createAccountBuy` expects only one account for the first parameter. You can either try to just do `$accounts[0]` to get the first one or `print_r($accounts)` and have a look which one you want to use.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has worked for you, so others can see that this has a solution. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Using the $accounts to pass the wallet ID over to the buying function work now.